# Как найти все слова определенной длины в неструктуированном тексте?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, geany

Ищу в куче абракадабры слово определенной длины, состоящее из букв и цифр. Я так понял, нужно использовать регулярные выражения.

Гуглил-гуглил, но максимум что нагуглил:

```
^\w{6,6}$
```

Но результат не впечатлил, так как там после слов без пробела идут скобки и прочие специальные символы. Я так понял, без пробела результат поиска не будет верным.

Как мне быть?

Comment: Какой язык программирования? `\w` разные вещи находит в .NET и JavaScript. Может, вам нужно `\b[^\W_]{6}\b`? [Демо](https://regex101.com/r/7PvOqV/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ТС в редакторе ищет. Там вроде perl подходит.

Comment: @simpleCode Да, я потом заметил Geany. Не знаю точно, какой там движок, так что подождём ответа. Если что, можно добавить варианты - `\b[\p{L}\p{N}]{6}\b`, `\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}\b`, `\b[[:alnum:]]{6}\b`.

Comment: Спасибо друзья, ваших вариантов достаточно

Answer (score 1):

Вместо начала и конца строи следует указывать границы слова:

```
\b\w{6}\b
```